# How can I write the correct path for rendering the picture?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have an issue trying to render a picture from my repo.
I have the skeleton of the component in a library and I'm rendering the component in a different repo, but I can't find the correct path to show the picture in the UI.

**Here is my code for the component in the library:**

```
<ThemeProvider theme={buyingTheme}>
      <Box display='flex' width='100%' justifyContent='center' alignItems='center'>
        <Box display='flex' sx={{ height:'445px', width:'445px', border: '1px solid red' }}>
          <Box
            height='306px'
            width='333px'
            sx={{
              paddingTop: '70px',
              paddingLeft: '47px',
              backgroundImage: `url(${picture})`,
              backgroundPosition: 'center',
              backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
              backgroundSize: 'contain',
            }}
          >
            {/* <img src={emptyStateLight} alt="Empty State" /> */}
          </Box>
        </Box>
        <Box display='flex' flexDirection='column' alignItems='left' sx={{ height:'136px', width:'445px', border: '1px solid blue', marginLeft: '20px' }}>
          <Typography variant="headings.h3" sx={{ height:'24px', paddingTop:'4px', paddingBottom:'4px' }}>{title}</Typography>
          <Typography
            variant="body.default"
            color="text.secondary"
            sx={{
              whiteSpace: 'pre-line',
              wordWrap: 'break-word',
              marginTop: '4px', height:'48px',
              paddingBottom:'4px', marginBottom: '4px',
            }}
          >
            {description}
          </Typography>
          <Button
            sx={{ height: '40px', width: '93px', padding:'20px', marginTop: 'auto' }}
            onClick={handleOnClick}
          >
            {buttonText}
          </Button>
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </ThemeProvider>
```

**Here is the code in the repo**

```
<EmptyState
        picture="public/picture.png"
        title="Title"
        description="Description multi-line Description
          multi-line Description
          multi-line"
        handleOnClick={() => {
          // TODO: Define your click handler function here
        }}
        buttonText="Button"
      />
```

The picture is in the folder public --> public\picture.png and my component is in --> src\pages\Layout\CollectionsTable\CollectionsTable.tsx

How can I fix the issue and show the picture?
I've tried many approaches but no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a typical React application, when you specify a **`url`** for a background image, it should be a relative path to the image file based on the public directory, which is the root for static assets. Here's how you can adjust your code:

Move the **picture.png** file to the **public** directory of your React app if it's not already there. So, you should have a structure like this:

```
public
|-- picture.png
src
|-- pages
    |-- Layout
        |-- CollectionsTable
            |-- CollectionsTable.tsx
```

In your **CollectionsTable.tsx** component, specify the url as a relative path to the **picture.png** file:

```
<ThemeProvider theme={buyingTheme}>
  <Box display='flex' width='100%' justifyContent='center' alignItems='center'>
    <Box display='flex' sx={{ height:'445px', width:'445px', border: '1px solid red' }}>
      <Box
        height='306px'
        width='333px'
        sx={{
          paddingTop: '70px',
          paddingLeft: '47px',
          backgroundImage: `url(./picture.png)`, // Relative path to the picture
          backgroundPosition: 'center',
          backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
          backgroundSize: 'contain',
        }}
      >
        {/* <img src={emptyStateLight} alt="Empty State" /> */}
      </Box>
    </Box>
    {/* Rest of your component */}
  </Box>
</ThemeProvider>
```

By specifying **./picture.png**, you are referencing the picture.png file from the root of your public directory, which is where static assets like images are served from in a React application.

Now, when you use your EmptyState component in the repo and specify **"public/picture.png"** as the **picture** prop, it should correctly reference the image

```
<EmptyState
  picture="public/picture.png"
  // Rest of your props
/>
```

Comment: Amazing! Now I can show the picture in the UI. Thanks a lot, sth new that I've learnt from you.

Comment: @mariadev.. Cheerrrrsss,.....  Happy Coding....